# I want to spell "from google.colab import files and uploaded= files.upload() in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

[image]

I think oh! I have to install google colab, and google in jupyter notebook, so

[image]

I installed google successfully, but

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, I want to cry... help me please

I installed google and google colab in jupyter, but somehow there's always an error.

I expect

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

to work without error